# cannot execute js code on 'new html code' that was added with jquery html() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have written some js code.

the structure of the code is as follows:

```
1. i load the page with basic html and js;
2. i make an ajax call (to php) and get the json variable;
3. i output the variable with some html code via jquery html
4. i would like to add  an extra code that is relevant to the html code i output on stage number '3'. i write the code with the general
js code in stage number '1' and it does not execute. it works oblt
when i add the js code to the variable containing html code on stage
'3'.
```

here is the code stracture:

html:

```
<div id="jsHtmlCodeHere"> </div>
```

js file:

```
    function getVeriableFromAjax(){
//ajax code is here
//successful ajax reuqest 200
    return 'hello world';
}

var ajaxData=getVeriableFromAjax();
var htmlCode="<button type='button' id='btn'>"+ajaxData+"</button>";

/*htmlCode += "<script>$('#btn').click(function(){alert('button clicked');});</script>"; this alert code works in my project only when i'm adding it to the 'htmlCode' variable.*/

$('#jsHtmlCodeHere').html(htmlCode);

$('#btn').click(function(){
    alert('button clicked');
});//this function does not execute in my code for some reason.
```

Anybody knows what is the problem? i would like to write the click function in stage number 1.

Thanks!

Comment: //use this code if html appended dynamically.
$(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
    alert("button clicked");
});

Comment: The issue is `$('#btn').click(function(){` works for static html only, for dynamic html try `$(document).on('click','#btn',function(){ alert("button clicked");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a watcher since the element you want to target is not on the page yet. You target the parent element and set a rule to match the future child.

```
$('#jsHtmlCodeHere').on('click', '#btn', function(){ alert('button clicked'); });
```

Comment: Thanks. now it is working! can you please give me an article on this issue? trying to find it without any luck on google

Comment: $('selector for element to watch children of').('event to trigger on', 'child element selector', function(){ triggered operation });